# Spring Data Neo4j - Adding custom analyzers to lucene indexes (PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper)

Tags: lucene, neo4j, spring-data, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Is it possible to customize lucene indexes in spring-data-neo4j, such that my indexes will be using custom analyzers? In particular, i want to use the PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzer, so i will be able to use Exact and Fulltext fields in the same index.
I saw a post about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/neo4j/2z9R2_czG5g), but it was related to native neo4j.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this over REST?

Comment: No, i'm using the embedded database.

Comment: Very curious how this works! @PeterNeubauer, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but people might still be interested:

We're currently using the lucene PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper analyzer in an embedded Neo4j project. Our interest was to have lemmatization. [The source code where the analyzer is set up in Neo4j.](https://github.com/SciGraph/SciGraph/blob/master/SciGraph-core/src/main/java/io/scigraph/neo4j/Neo4jModule.java#L82)
See also [this ticket](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1346).

We're running Neo4j 2.2.8, but unfortunately I'm having trouble to achieve the same with Neo4j 3.0.1, quite a lot have changed in Lucene 5.5.0 API.

Hope that helps.